# App not 64 bit compliant but doesn't include native code

Tags: android, gradle, 64-bit

I've been struggling to get my app 64 bit compliant.  I even tried creating a new empty app using the same package name and signing key as my old app.  The new app is 100% boilerplate code and I'm getting this message after uploading it to the play store.  What am I missing?  I'm starting to wonder if this message is completely erroneous.

```
This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement. The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: . Learn more
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.name"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1038
        versionName "7.7.1038"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I've read the url provded in "Learn More."  As far as I can tell, the only thing that I needed to do to the empty app was add this to the build.gradle file:

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

Comment: I suspect this had something to do with the play console.  It no longer has this issue with the exact same code.  As a matter of fact, none of the messages with the blue exclamations are showing, good or bad.

Comment: Have you solved your problem, please share it with us